# how can i add a subterm of taxonomy in code

Tags: taxonomy-terms

```
$vocabulary = (object) array(
'name' => st('A'),
'description' => st('A'),
'machine_name' => 'user_a',
'help' => 'test for subterm',
);
taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocabulary);

$user_a=array(st('A'),st('B'));

$user_a_vid=db_select('taxonomy_vocabulary', 'tv')
  ->fields('tv', array('vid'))
  ->condition('machine_name', 'user_a')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();

foreach ($user_a as $name) {
    $term = new stdClass;
    $term->name = $name;
    $term->vid = $user_a_vid;
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
 }
```

i have two vocabulary A and B

and i want to add sub-term of A and B

A have sub-term 1,2
B have sub-term 3,4

how can i do that in code?

Thanks for reading my question~thx~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeh~

i found out,this code can fix all the problem

```
$term->parent = $parent_tid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you may be able to use the [Taxonomy CSV](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) module.  This module allows you to create a CSV file and import taxonomy vocabularies (including subterms/hierarchy structures).

Comment: thx for sharing, but i want to write a .install file and create taxonomy by program. But this module is still useful for me. Thx a lot ! Do u know how to write the code?